# Is it possible that size of directory exceed one block size?

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory

I have known that in Linux one directory must occupy one data block to store file links consisting of `inumber` or sth. else. However, if there are thousands of files in this directory, is it true that this directory would occupy more data blocks?

Hope for your help. :-)

Comment: What filesystem specifically is your question about? The details of the answers may differ depending on filesystem.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have no idea of which filesystem should be covered. Could you clarify it?

Answer (score 2):

A *nix system makes no difference between a file and a directory, whereby a directory is just a file containing names of other files (and numbers of inodes). Therefore, as the content of a directory grows with the amount of files it contains, the size (blocks) used to store this content will grow as well. To my knowledge. it will **not** shrink when files are deleted within this directory.

Comment: 'it will not shrink when files are deleted within this directory.' Why?

Comment: Lets say you have 1000 files in  this directory and you delete file no. 2-999, then you have file no. 1 at the beginning of the 'directory-file' and file no.1000 at the end of the 'directory-file' left in the directory. To my knowledge *nix will not optimize this 'directory-file' but reuse it for future new files copied, moved or created in this directory.

Comment: Like the filesystem marks the deleted file entry in the directory as empty(`inumber=0`). When new files are generated into this directory, the empty entry would be overwritten. Is it right?

Comment: Whether a directory shrinks or not when entries are deleted, and the exact way the directory is managed, depends on the particular filesystem that the directory lives on.